# TYPO3 7.2.0 issue with Fluid rendering

Tags: typo3, fluid

I'm currently developing a site on the new T3 7.2.0

When I use `f:format.html`, T3 will render after almost every tag one to four empty `p.bodytext`s appear. *Good thing*: The paragraphs I made in the RTE are wrapped as well inside a `p.bodytext`.

When I use `f:format.raw`, no additional `p.bodytext`s are being rendered. Unfortunately, there even won't be any of them even though they are explicitly mentioned inside the RTE.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

The `f:format.html` ViewHelper filters its input through a `parseFunc`, which is for example used to render the content from a field filled by a RTE. The default `parseFunc` is for the default RTE, it does things like replacing custom link tags that the editor saves:

```
<link 13#112>Linktext</link>
```

becomes something like this

```
<a href="/index.php?id=13#c112">Linktext</a>
```

This transformation does some more things, e.g. inserting paragraphs, as you noticed.

Solution: Just print your fields without an ViewHelper, except the field was filled by a RTE. Then use `f:format.html`.